# Run Symmetricds latest on Docker

Tags: symmetricds

I am trying to install Symmetric DS on Docker which is running under PhotonOS.
Since I just installed another Docker Image, I have at least some basic knowledge.

I run exactly these commands:

https://hub.docker.com/r/jumpmind/symmetricds

Which works so far untill I get

```
2024-01-04 21:47:38,623 INFO [startup] [SymmetricWebServer] [main] About to start SymmetricDS         web server on 0.0.0.0:31415                                               :HTTP/1.1
2024-01-04 21:47:38,762 INFO [startup] [SymmetricEngineHolder] [main] Current directory is /opt/symmetric-ds
2024-01-04 21:47:38,762 INFO [startup] [SymmetricEngineHolder] [main] Starting in multi-server mode with engines director                                               y at /opt/symmetric-ds/engines
2024-01-04 21:47:38,762 INFO [startup] [SymmetricEngineHolder] [main] No engine *.properties files found
2024-01-04 21:47:39,178 INFO [startup] [SymmetricWebServer] [main] Joining the web server main thread
Stopping abandoned wrapper PID 29
```

First of all I wonder, shouldnt a Docker Image more or less simply work and more important what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In the Symmetric Docker image, there seams to be no basic *.properties file.
This file contains the fundamental settings without the startup reports errors.

If you don't know the basic concepts of SymmetricDS, just follow these steps:
https://symmetricds.sourceforge.net/doc/3.12/html/tutorials.html

If you want more quickly to try out SymmetricDS, simply download it on Windows or Linux, install the latest JAVA from Oracle and follow the guide above.
It takes about 30 minutes to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

this is the culprit

```
No engine *.properties files found
```

please provide the engine configuration file.

Comment: That's the point, there are no *.properties files. There should be at least a demo files which provides enough information, so the first start runs through and there is a link to the manual to explain the setup. Now I got so far. But that took a long time to find the missing path. There should be some more information about the basic concept, so the user can dive in.